# How to modify each value of a nested object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

How can I multiply every nested value of this object by X (e.g. 0.5)?

```js
const myObject = {
    base: {
        serving: {
            size: 100
        }
    },
    fat: {
        acids: {
            monoUnsaturatedFattyAcids: 12
            polyUnsaturatedFattyAcids: 3
            saturatedFattyAcids: 2
        },
    }
}
```

The object is sometimes nested up to 10 levels deep.

Comment: What have you tried and what was the problem?

Comment: `for...in...`, `for...of...`

Comment: i have a giant object where all values need to be scaled often. i don't like to hard code this by hand. I tried to loop other all the properties, but this seemed inefficient and was only partially successful.

Comment: the object ist sometimes nested up to 10 levels deep.

Comment: Why is this information missing in your question? And as already said... What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: "but this seemed inefficient" why? There is no built in way to multiply every property by some value in an arbitrary object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a generator that will provide an iterator over every nested key/value pair (together with the nested object), so that you can do what you want with it inside a `for` loop:

```js
function * iter(obj) {
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
        if (Object(value) !== value) yield [obj, key, value];
        else yield * iter(value);
    }
}

// demo
const myObject = {
    base: {
        serving: {
            size: 100
        }
    },
    fat: {
        acids: {
            monoUnsaturatedFattyAcids: 12,
            polyUnsaturatedFattyAcids: 3,
            saturatedFattyAcids: 2
        },
    }
};

for (let [obj, key, value] of iter(myObject)) {
    if (typeof value === "number") obj[key] *= 0.5; // multiply by 0.5
}
// The object has been mutated accordingly
console.log(myObject);
```

Comment: thank you very much! what is the asterix * used for in 'function * iter(obj) ...'

Comment: Andrea, it is JavaScript syntax for a special kind of function called [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*). It allows the function to use the `yield` keyword, and  act accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested here's an explanation:

You can try something like a function that recursively iterates through the properties of an object and depending on said property its type, multiply or call our recursive function again.

These are the steps the function takes:

1. We use the `Object.keys` method to get an `array` containing all property names as strings of our object
2. We iterate through our `keys` array
3. for every `key` we check if `obj[key]` its value is either a `number` or something else.

note about `obj[key]`: by using square braces you can access properties of an object by passing a string. e.g `obj['base']` is equivalent to `obj.base`

4. if it's type is indeed `number`, multiply `obj[key]` by 0.5! Don't forget to actually assign the value to the property.
5. if it ain't a `number`, call the function again, but this time we use the object stored in `obj[key]`.

e.g. when you pass `myObject` to the function, the first `key` will be `base`, `obj.base` contains an object, so we call `recursiveMultiplication(obj.base)` and the cycle continues.
until every `recursiveMultiplication` call runs out of keys to iterate through.

When all is said and done, the original object should contain mutated values.

If you don't wish to mutate you should clone the object using something like `rfdc`. using `{...spread}` won't cut it for nested objects.

```js
const myObject = {
  base: {
    serving: {
      size: 100
    }
  },
  fat: {
    acids: {
      monoUnsaturatedFattyAcids: 12,
      polyUnsaturatedFattyAcids: 3,
      saturatedFattyAcids: 2
    }
  }
};

const recursiveMultiplication = (obj) => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => typeof obj[key] === "number" ? obj[key] = obj[key] * 0.5 : recursiveMultiplication(obj[key]))

  return obj;
};

console.log(recursiveMultiplication(myObject));
```

Comment: This is a good solution. Could you try to comment, so future readers can learn what the code means? A good answer should preferably be teaching, and not just something to copy/paste ;)

Answer (score 1):

```js
    function modifyValues(obj) {
      for (let key in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[key] === "object") {
          modifyValues(obj[key]);
        }else {
          obj[key] = obj[key] * 0.5;
        }
      }
      return obj;
    }
    console.log(modifyValues({
    "a": 5,
    "b": {
        "c": 10
    },
    "d": {
        "e": 15,
        "f": {
            "g": 20
        }
    }
}))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think the best is to use a library to ease the traverse of the nested object.

```
const _ = require('lodash')

const myObject = {
  base: {
      serving: {
          size: 100
      }
  },
  fat: {
      acids: {
          monoUnsaturatedFattyAcids: 12,
          polyUnsaturatedFattyAcids: 3,
          saturatedFattyAcids: 2
      },
  }
}

const newObjValue = _.cloneDeepWith(myObject, x => typeof x === 'number'? x*0.5: undefined)

console.log(newObjValue)
```

Comment: _"I think the best is to use a library"_ - Why? And why do you clone the object?

Comment: I would say lodash is quite standard library. Most people would understand the cloneDeepWith. And if they don't they could go to the lodash documentation... or do online search for support. Building your own function to something so general as traverse (like the first answer...) you will be on your own, and your code will not be as readable for other people.
Why clone? It is always a good practice not to mutate objects. This is part of functional programming.

Answer (score 0):

Here is quick solution. I have not added cases for arrays. need to add them if you expect arrays at the top level or nested inside.

```
const myObject = {
    base: {
        serving: {
            size: 100
        }
    },
    fat: {
        acids: {
            monoUnsaturatedFattyAcids: 12,
            polyUnsaturatedFattyAcids: 3,
            saturatedFattyAcids: 2
        },
    }
}

function isArray ( obj ) { 
    return isObject(obj) && (obj instanceof Array);
}

function isObject ( obj ) {
    return obj && (typeof obj  === "object");
}

function recursiveMultiplyNumberFields(myObject, X){
//Assuming that at the top level, what you pass on is a dictionar object. If it could be arrays as well, need to handle more cases
    for (key in myObject){
        if (isNaN(myObject [key])==false){
            myObject[key] = X*myObject[key];
        }
        else if(isArray(myObject [key])){
                /*not taken care as of now. Need to do if ararys are expected inside*/
        }
        else if(typeof myObject [key] === 'object' && myObject [key] !== null){
            recursiveMultiplyNumberFields(myObject [key],X)
        }
        else{
            //not a number and not a object. So need not do anything
        }
        
    }
}
console.log("Before mult",myObject);
recursiveMultiplyNumberFields(myObject,5);
console.log("After mult",myObject);
```